# PL/SQL/Oracle DB: Procedure: ORA-29013: SSL MAC verification failure (Database 19c)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, oracle19c

Procedure that was developed on database Oracle 12c returns the following error, when ran on database Oracle 19c.

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-29013: SSL MAC verification failure
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 797
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1335
ORA-06512: at "xxxx.xxxx_xxx_xxxxxx", line 318
ORA-06512: at line 12
```

I have tried researching this and I have not found any good answers on how to resolve this issue. If anyone could provide me the cause of this issue or a solution, that's be awesome.

I am trying to call an API, which returns a file and saves into a blob. As previously mentioned, this functionality works perfectly fine on 12c.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This [seems to be a known bug](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2776450_1.html), so you probably need to patch it.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yeah, I figured. I'll contact the database administrator to patch it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out... [they mitght be at same page as you.](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4482100/ora-29013-ssl-mac-verification-failure/p3)

It seens they solved by applying the patch 32738356.

Since they find out that an update from 19.9 to 19.10 fixed their problem. Same as you have now. What is you current version?

Please, if you try it out, give us some feedback. :)

Best regards.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That is indeed the patch, that fixes the issue.